# Need Help Beginner Java Program "STRINGS"

Tags: java, string

Hey guys so im new to java and im trying to write a program that declares two strings 
First && Last name ( both under case )
And i need to use the .uppercase to convert the first letter in both the first name and last name from lower case to uppercase.

Example convert jon to Jon

This is what i have so far
I really dont understand how i make the first letter uppercase.

```
/////
public class firstProgram {
public static void main(String args[])
{
//NAME GOES HERE. DECLARED 2 STRINGS
String first = "firstname";
String last = "lastname";

//PRINT OUT STRINGS
System.out.println(first);
System.out.println(last);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like -

```
    String first = "firstname";
    String last = "lastname";
    first = String.valueOf(first.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + first.substring(1);
    last = String.valueOf(last.charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + last.substring(1);
    //PRINT OUT STRINGS
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(last);
```

You can check [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29) for toUpperCase().

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to capitalize the first letter of a string named `first` and leave the rest alone:

```
first = first.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + first.substring(1);
```

Now `first` will have what you want.
Do like this for `last`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by employing the String class subString methods.

```
String input = "first name";
String out = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
firstName = Character.toUpperCase(firstName.charAt(0)) + firstName.substring(1);

lastName = Character.toUpperCase(lastName.charAt(0)) + lastName.substring(1);
```

or in class

```
class FirstProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstName = "arun";
        String lastName = "kumar";
        firstName = Character.toUpperCase(firstName.charAt(0)) + firstName.substring(1);
        lastName = Character.toUpperCase(lastName.charAt(0)) + lastName.substring(1);
        System.out.println(firstName+ " "+lastName);    
    }
}
```